# How to load a movie from network share in FFMPEG's filters?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to overlay a video on top of another using ffmpeg filters but I have problem with escaping of the file path when it is on a network share.

```
ffmpeg -i "\\my_nas\path\to\source.mov" -vf "movie='\\my_nas\how\to\properly\escape\this\path.mov'[clip2]; [in] scale=640:360,pad=640:368:0:0:white [resized]; [resized][clip2] overlay=W-128:H-8 [out]" ...other params... -y "\\my_nas\path\to\dest.mp4"
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. `net use k: \\my_nas\share_name`
2. `ffmpeg -i k:\path\to\source.mov -vf "movie='k:\no\escaping\this\path.mov'[clip2]; [in] scale=640:360,pad=640:368:0:0:white [resized]; [resized][clip2] overlay=W-128:H-8 [out]" ...other params... -y "k:\path\to\dest.mp4"`

Comment: The `movie` multimedia source filter can be omitted if `-filter_complex` is used instead of `-vf`: `ffmpeg -i movie1.mov -i movie2.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]scale,pad[resized];[resized][1:v]overlay" ... output`

Comment: E.G. : It's not the question. My script is actually running like you said but I whant to avoid connecting a network drive. You also forget to escape the ":" it should be like this "movie=k\:\\no\\escaping... thanks anyway.
@LordNeckbeard : Thanks for the tip, but why did you post it as a comment ? Please repost it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @bokan I do not consider it an answer but more of an addition to E.G.'s answer.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard : no, E.G. answer does not open files with network share url (\\NAS\) wich is what I want. Your solution allows to do that.